# c# - How can I add a value to a multi array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array here:

```
float[, ,] vectors;

int pos = 0;

void Start() {
   vectors = new float[,,] { {
       { 0, 1, 1 }, 
       { 0, 2, 2 } }
    };        
}
```

This works. I fill the array with numbers.

Now I want to add some values again to a given position. But how?

This are not working:

```
vectors[pos] = new float[,,] { { { 33, 44, 55 } } };
```

or

```
vectors[pos] = { { { 33, 44, 55 } } };
```

I searched, but not found the right answer.

EDIT:
I want something like this:

```
[0]+
   [0] {1, 2, 3},
   [1] {4, 5, 6}

[1]+
   [0] {11, 22, 33},
   [1] {44, 55, 66},
   [2] {77, 88, 99}

...
etc.
```

Now, e.g. I want add values {10,10,10} to pos = 0. But how?

Comment: you are declaring it as a multidimensional array, but using it as an array of arrays [of arrays]. [see the differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: You might want to use a Vector class and put them into a generic list instead of a multi-dimentional array.

Comment: How can I solve it with an array? I want a three-dimensional array. Is this not possible?

Comment: Are you saying you need two dimensions to identify a given vector and the last dimension is just to index the 3 values of a vector?

Comment: @juharr. I edited the question. Please look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add values I suggest using generic lists instead of arrays.  And you should create your own Vector class or find one that is suitable to your needs like this.

```
public class Vector
{
    public float X { get; private set; }
    public float Y { get; private set; }
    public float Z { get; private set; }

    public Vector(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following

```
var vectors = new List<List<Vector>>
{
    new List<Vector>{
        new Vector(0, 1, 1),
        new Vector(0, 2, 2)
    }
};

vectors[0].Add(new Vector(33,44,55));
```

And your vectors will contain

```
[0]
    [0] {0, 1, 1}
    [1] {0, 2, 2}
    [2] {33, 44, 55}
```

Note that if you need to add to the first dimention you have to do this.

```
vectors.Add(new List<Vector>());

vectors[1].Add(new Vector(1, 2, 3));
```

And now you have

```
[0]
    [0] {0, 1, 1}
    [1] {0, 2, 2}
    [2] {33, 44, 55}
[1]
    [0] {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: the reason it works is because it is not using static arrays which are contiguous blocks of memory and cannot be changed after assignment for that reason, they are a better way to represent what you are doing. the answer I provided does essentially the same thing, although List will have a capacity it provides by default and so is a little more efficient. This answer also has the advantage of giving you a strong type to address your coordinates. Allthough if its just points I'd argue a struct is better.

Answer (score 0):

You should determine the other positions within the array, you are just specifying one. If your problem cannot be solved within lists 
you can try array of arrays as follows

```
float [][][] x = new float [n][m][];

// initialize the third dimension until m is reached
x[0] = new float {1,2,3,4,5}; // specify whatever value you want
x[1] = new float {3,2,4};
x[2] = new float [3];

// etc until m is reached
// do the same for the n dimension
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, the array is assigned, you cannot change it you must expand the array as is.

```
float[, ,] vectors;

int pos = 0;

vectors = new float[,,]
{
    { 
        { 0, 1, 2 }, { 0, 3, 4 }
    }
};        


vectors =  new float[,,]
    {
        {
            {vectors[0,0,0], vectors[0,0,1], vectors[0,0,2]}, { vectors[0,1,0], vectors[0,1,1], vectors[0,1,2] }, { 33,44,55}
        }
    };
```

Comment: This works. I know. But I can't add new values to the position that I want. This is only for changing the values.

Comment: Are you saying you want more entries, because that can't be done without dynamically expanding the array